# Changing a styled components style by toggling state after page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm able to change a styled components styles based on state but only at page load, if I toggle the state after page load, the state changes successfully but the styles remain the same. The styled component whose styles I'm trying to change is "S.Search" which is inside of a "Search" component whose parent is "Navbar". I'm passing "Search" an "isVisible" state as a prop that is toggled by the onClick event handler in the parent component "Navbar".

The parent component:

```js
    import React, { useContext, useState } from "react"
    import Search from "../components/Search"
    import * as S from "../styled/Navbar"

    const Navbar = () => {

      const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false)
      return (
        <S.Navbar>
          /* S.SearchButton toggles the isVisible state onclick */
              
              <S.SearchButton onClick={() => setVisibility(!isVisible)}>
                <S.SearchButtonText>Search</S.SearchButtonText>
              </S.SearchButton>
            
            /* Passing isVisible state into the Search component as props */
            
            <Search isVisible={isVisible} setVisibility={setVisibility} />
        </S.Navbar>
      )
    }

    export default Navbar
```

The search component:

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react"
    import Icon from "../components/Icon"
    import * as S from "../styled/Search"

    const Search = props => {
      return (
        <S.Search>
          <S.InputWrapper>
            <S.SearchButtonIcon>
              <Icon icon={"search"} />
            </S.SearchButtonIcon>
            <S.Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for a character"
              autocomplete="off"
            />
            <S.ChampList></S.ChampList>
          </S.InputWrapper>
        </S.Search>
      )
    }

    export default Search
```

I'm sure my state is being toggled correctly, but I have no idea why the style isn't being updated when toggling the state after page load. This is the styled component that has access to the isVisible state via props passed to the search component:

```js
    import styled from "styled-components"

    export const Search = styled.div`
      height: ${p => (!p.isVisible ? `0` : `2.5rem`)};
      visibility: ${p => (!p.isVisible ? `hidden` : `visible`)};
      opacity: ${p => (!p.isVisible ? `0` : `100`)};
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      transition: ${p => p.theme.easings.easeOut};

    `
```

How can I change the style after page load when I toggle the state? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style isnt being applied because you are not passing `isVisible` prop to `Search` style-component.

You just need to do this in your `Search Component`:

```js
const Search = props => {
      return (
        // Here´s the trick
        <S.Search isVisible={props.isVisible}>
         .....
         .....
         .....
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I was thrown off by this because the styles were changing, just not after page load, and I wasnt getting an error that "props.isVisible" is not defined, so I thought the styled component was just implicitly being passed the state and this wasn't necessary. Why is it necessary to pass it the state like this?

Comment: Hi @Peeper, its necessary because styled components works like a react component in this case. You can check more [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

Comment: Also another way to do this is: `<S.Search {...props}>`, in this case you will foward all component props to styled component.

Comment: Any idea why this is causing all components to rerender the first time the state is toggled?  How can I stop this from happening? Is it because I'm passing the state down to 2 child components?

Comment: Hi @Peeper, i didnt get it... do you have two `<S.Search>` ?

Comment: isVisible is created in the navbar component which is passed to the search component, then S.Search.